# Driving Traffic from other websites and AdSense?

Tags: google-adsense, traffic, google-adsense-policies, web-traffic, parking

I own multiple domain names. Most of them are parked with some parking service provider. I also have few WordPress sites I maintain. Last week I applied for AdSense and got accepted, and placed ads. However, I want to increase the traffic flow into my WordPress sites.

I was thinking to unpark all the domains I have and point them all to my WordPress site. Will that cause an issue with AdSense?

Some might argue that I should leave them parked, but I made than same amount in a week with AdSense than 6 months with the parking provider...

Comment: Having domain names that are then redirected to another site does absolutely nothing for you. You need to gain traffic the old fashioned way - hard work.

Comment: Not redirect - the NS will point to that same server/folder.

Comment: Either way, adding domain names do nothing for site traffic. It is like adding labels/ model names to the back of your car. It is still one car with the same capacity to haul butts around as before.

Comment: Adsense does not care where the traffic comes from in this case?

Comment: It has nothing to do with Adsense. Adding domain names to a site does not add traffic or value. What does add value and traffic is a good solid site that people want to visit again and again along with engagement to keep them interested.

Comment: I don't think you get what I'm asking. I have domain example.com with good content. And example2.com which is parked and has thousands of page landings. If instead of having it parked with nameservers set to ns1.park.com I'll point it to the server/ folder where example.com is hosted so example.com will generate more traffic...

Comment: I get what you are saying. It will not help you gain traffic. In fact, it can significantly reduce whatever traffic you already have if you do not deal with the duplicate content issue. Adding domain names to a single set of content does absolutely nothing for you no matter how you chose to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't point the nameservers to the same server, this way you'll have multiple domains with the same content. You'll get a bit more revenue at the start, but when the duplicate content penalty sets in, you'll probably lose traffic to both sites.

I would 301 redirect the parked sites to the actual site. This way, you won't get the duplicate content issue. Your parked site will disappear from the SERPs if the 301 is in place too long, but since it's a parked site, I'm assuming it's not being returned in search results anyway.

Either option shouldn't be a problem for Adsense by the way. It's real traffic with real clicks.

All of this assumes your parked domain is getting traffic on its own. It won't help you get more traffic in any way.